# How to Create Connection Pools for Digital Ocean Managed Postgres Database using SSL with Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, ssl, digital-ocean

I writing an API using nodejs and express. My database got hacked and I decided to use the Digital Ocean Managed Database. Digital Ocean Managed database requires SSL and they ONLY provide you with one CA certificate. In all the tutorials out there, SSL requires 3 files.  I didn't find any tutorial on how to connect node-pg with only one file. I finally found the solution and I want to share it with the community. Hopefully, I save someone a few hours of digging.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The certificate that the Digital Ocean provides you is a Root Certificate NOT Client Certificate. In node-pg `cert` is referring to the client certificate and `CA` refers to the root certificate. `CA` option is the one that should be used, not `Cert`.

1. CA: root.crt (For Incoming messages; Digital Ocean gives you this one)
2. Key: postgresql.key (You don't need it)
3. Cert: Client Certificate (You don't need it)

```js
const config = {
  database: 'database-name',
  host: 'host-or-ip',
  user: 'username',
  password: 'password',
  port: 1234,
  // this object will be passed to the TLSSocket constructor
  ssl: {
    ca: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/digitalOcean/certificate.crt').toString()
  }
}
```

If this answer was useful to you give a thumbs up so other people can find it as well.